# Loop through fields in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I have a table. Each row contains form fields that can be populated or not by the user. I need to check that for each row either all the form fields are populated or none.

The html is this:

```
<tr class="riga_gar">
    <td class="report">     
        <input type="hidden" id="crediti[<?php echo $i; ?>]" name="crediti[<?php echo $i; ?>]"
                    value="<?php echo $cred['id_cre']; ?>" >
            <?php echo $cred['id_cre'] ?>
    </td>
    <td class="report gbv" data-gbv="<?php echo $cred['gbv_tot']; ?>">
        <?php echo num2cur($cred['gbv_tot']); ?>
    </td>
    <td class="report">
        <?php echo veicolo2name($cred['titolare'],$pdo); ?>
    </td>
    <td class="report">
        <?php echo $cred['stato']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="report">
        <input class="input_field numerico" id="chiesto" type="text" name="garanzia[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo $chiesto; ?>">
    </td>
    <td class="report">
        <select name="tipo_gar[<?php echo $i; ?>]">
            <option value="">Scegli</option>
            <?php foreach($tipo_gars as $tipo_gar){
                echo '<option value="'.$tipo_gar['id'].'">'.$tipo_gar['descrizione'].'</option>';
                            }?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to do is to check that for each row both the input and the select have a value or none.

I started with this js:

```
function ajax_submit(){
    var submit_val=$("#garante").serialize();
    dest="anagrafiche/new_garante1.php";
    $('.riga_gar').each(function(i,obj){
        if ($(this).val()!='') {
        }
    });
}
```

and I want to run this ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: dest,
    data: submit_val,
    success: function(data){ 
        data1=data.split("|");
        if(data1[0]=="Successo"){ 
            $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
            function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass("spn_success").html(data1[1]).fadeTo(900,1)});
        }else if(data1[0]=="Errore"){
            $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
            function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass("spn_error").html(data1[1]).fadeTo(900,1)});  
        }
    },
    complete: function(){
        $.fancybox.close();
    //setTimeout(function(){ $('.container').load('sofferenze/dashboard.php?from=<?php echo $id_soff ?>');},3000); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#upper').load('sofferenze/soff.php?soff=<?php echo $id_soff ?>');
        $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
            function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass("spn_normal").html('Cruscotto della sofferenza <?php echo soff2name($id_soff,$pdo); ?>').fadeTo(900,1)});
    },3000); 
    } //chiudo complete function
}); //chiudo $.ajax
```

only when:

1. at least one row have both values;
2. all the rows that have values have both of them;

but I get stuck at how to refer to the value of input and select in the each loop so that I can check my conditions.

Comment: select has default value i think, you just want to check if input is populated or not?

Comment: I only see one row in your HTML - did you mean you need to check if a value in one of the columns is filled out?

Comment: No. The select need to be not with the default value. But the issue is not on the conditions. The point is in the each: how to refer to the input and select that are in the row selected by the each

Comment: @MatthewHerbst there is one row only because this is the row structure. In the table there will be as many of this row as rows fetched from the db

Comment: You do realize that this **is not** HTML, right?

Comment: Didn't get your point. I am speaking about jQuery syntax. And the tag in my question says the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you. This will read each row and ignore your hidden field. Once code will find both values populated than validateForm variable will be true and will become false if in next row one value from both input or select will be empty.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var validateForm = false;
    var check = 0;
    $("form").on('submit',function(){
        $("tr").each(function(){
            console.log($.trim($(this).find("input.input_field").val()) +", "+ $.trim($(this).find("select").val()));
            if($.trim($(this).find("input.input_field").val()) != "" && $.trim($(this).find("select").val()) != ""){
                validateForm = true;
            }
            else{

                if($.trim($(this).find("input.input_field").val())  == "" && $.trim($(this).find("select").val()) != ""){
                    if(validateForm){
                        validateForm = false;
                        check = 1;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                if($.trim($(this).find("input.input_field").val())  != "" && $.trim($(this).find("select").val()) == ""){
                    if(validateForm){
                        validateForm = false;
                        check = 1;
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            }

        });
        if(validateForm && check == 0){
              validateForm = true;
            }
        else{
            validateForm = false;
        }
        if(validateForm){
            //call ajax
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/87tkraas/

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but how about something like this:

```
var allowSubmit = false;

$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    $("tr").each(function() {
        var input = $(this).find("input").val();
        var select= $(this).find("select").val();
        if ((input == "" && select != "") || (input != "" && select == "")) {
            return;
        } else if (input != "" && select != "") {
            allowSubmit = true;
        }
    });
    if (allowSubmit == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```